# Adding Custom Body Class for Page: Shop

Tags: functions, body-class

been hacking at this for some time and haven't been able to make much progress. The goal is to add a custom body class to a specific page. -I know there are a few answered posts on this topic, and while the solution provided works if I add the custom body class globally, it fails when I add the if statement. Any ideas of what might prevent this from registering the custom body class?

These Fail:

```
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if (is_page('shop'))
        $classes[] = 'services';
    return $classes;
}
```

Or

```
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    if (is_page('4'))
        $classes[] = 'services';
    return $classes;
}
```

but this works, unfortunately globally:

```
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
  //  if (is_page('shop'))
        $classes[] = 'services';
    return $classes;
}
```

I am on Genesis Framework, WPEngine, have WooCommerce and all are up to date. -Weird.

Comment: I don't know if you are working with WooCommerce but in case I would suggest to use `is_shop()` as condition.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use this:

```
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID == 346) {
        $classes[] = 'services';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

This can be used anywhere as its pulling the global variable first.

Answer (score 0):

This will works! Fine

```
add_filter('body_class','shop_body_classes');
function shop_body_classes($classes){
    if (is_shop()){   
        $classes[] = 'class-name-1';
        $classes[] = 'class-name-2';    
    } 
    return $classes;  
}
```